# Jump forward and backwards in for loop

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I have some problems figuring out how to implement a for loop in C++(14).
It's a normal for loop:

```
for (j = 65; j < 91; ++j) {
    body...
}
```

For the first iteration j will be 65. For the second iteration, I want it to be increased by 32 (second iteration j = 97). For the third, it has to go back to 65 + 1 => 66.
Basically, j values will be like this: 65, 97, 66, 98, 67, 99, 68, 100, 69, 101... and so on. I want the code to be minimal when talking about character used.

P.S: If it's helpful, those values are the ASCII value for `A, a, B, b, C, c, D, d, F, f...`

TL;DR: I wanna iterate through those integers/chars in as less code as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags! 2) Don't use magic numbers.

Comment: Just have your body call a function to do the work twice with the values `j` and `j+32` respectively.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, cuz a while can be transformed in a for loop or vice-versa.

Comment: @clcto i've done a lambda function. and i've called it for j and j + 32, but i tought there can be another solution with less characters.

Comment: @Olaf "cuz" = shorthand "because"

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thx for missing the point ;-)

Comment: *"there can be another solution with less characters"* -- Don't go with the shortest possible solution, go with the *most readable* and *most obviously correct* solution. E.g., if you have to do more than a little reasoning about a possible solution to prove that it works correctly, it's probably the wrong one.

Comment: @Olaf Back at ya for veiling it =P

Comment: If you're writing code golf, that's on you.  You have some workable solutions.

Comment: @Donnie Yeah. It's codegolf. But i feel like i've done everything i could to make the solution as small as possible and a little help won't bother anyone.

Comment: @aleeN1 then you posted on the wrong site. Try: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2079303 i didn't know about that site till now. thank you :D

Comment: Well, obviously it is an interview question :-)

Comment: @napuzba have you been asked to codegolf in an interview? :D

Comment: @user2079303 yes - It was bizarre interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider that on first iteration. consider fact on first iteration (i=0) you have pair of values (current=65, next=97), on second (current=97, next = 68)

```
for(char c = 65, n=97; c+n<=213; ++c,c^=n,n^=c,c^=n)
   body
```

shortening it

```
  for(char c = 65, n=97; n<123; swap(c,n), c++)
```

or

```
  for(char c = 65, n=97; n!=91; swap(c,n), c++)
```

binary representation of  65 is 100 0001, of 97 - 101 0001, and so on,
so even steps can be created from odd ones by bitwise or c ^ 32. increments must be done only on odd steps. if we assume, that implicit cast of boolean true to integral value yield 1, it looks so

```
  for(char c = 65; c!=91; c^=32, c+=c<91)
```

if above not true

```
  for(char c = 65; c!=91; c^=32, c+=1-c/91)
```

just equally short solution, that uses preliminary step of for loop and fact that assignment operator returns value

```
  for(char c = 64; (c+=c<91)!=91; c^=32)
```

NB. NEVER write your loops like that unless you want everyone who reads code to hate you

Comment: ;* it's not a real contest tho. it's just something between me and my friends. THANK YOU. but what about the code being shorted? can it be?

Comment: Comma operator is/was sequence point, now it should be said that it sequences left operand before right one. i was thinking about leaving only one variable , but ^ works only with power of two increments apparently

Comment: i found out how to shorten it. Instead of "++c,c^=n,n^=c,c^=n" i put "swap(c, n), ++n".

Comment: @aleeN1 well, if you allowed to use swap, why, yes. those are essentially a swap without temporal

Answer (score 4):

Just use two iteration variables

```
for(auto lo=65, hi=lo+32; lo!=91; ++lo,++hi) {
  /* use lo */
  /* use hi */
}
```

The compiler may optimize either or both of `lo` and `hi` away. Otherwise, you can add to a single iteration variable

```
void work(int);
for(auto j=65; j!=91; ++j) {
  work(j);
  work(j+32);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just iterate over those values:

```
for(auto ch : {'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'F', 'f'}) {
   /* use ch */
}
```

Comment: This is *the* way to do it in an encoding independent way.

Comment: I said i need to use as less code as possible. Obviously you can do that...

Comment: @aleeN1 I'm curious as to why you are aiming for the least amount of code. Is this a programming competition? In any professional scenario, amount of code is nearly useless as a metric of quality. If you are "trying to figuring out how to implement a for loop" minimizing the quantity of code is senseless.

Comment: anything else would be longer in code and less obvious

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's a code golf. A contest where the winner is the one who solve the problems using the least code.

Comment: @aleeN1 A Code Golf solves *no* problems, and are done for fun. Unless you’re writing for IOCCC, don’t use the shortest code, use the most obvious code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to jump back and forth.  Iterate through one range of characters and use `toupper`/`tolower` to go the the opposite character.  For example

```
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
{
    char lower = tolower(ch);
    //use ch
    //use lower
}
```

As long as `'A'` to `'Z'` is a contiguous range this will work just fine.  If you do not have a contiguous range you can use something like

```
for (char ch = std::numeric_limits<char>::min(); ch <= std::numeric_limits<char>::max(); ch++)
{
    if(isalpha(ch) && isupper(ch))
    {
        char lower = tolower(ch);
        //use ch
        //use lower
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use ^=

```
for (j = 65; j < 91; ++j,j^=' ') {
    body...
}
```

Comment: it looks good in terms of characters used. but it does not do the job. j goes to 65, 98 then exit...

Comment: By the way, you can use 32 instead of ' '. So there are only 6 chars.

Comment: hah, i was thinking how to collapse that 32 gap.. didnt though of ^=

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is short.  I believe this wins.

```
for (j=65;j!=91;(j^=' '),j+=(j<91))
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/255774b6bbd02249).

Comment: hm, incrementing by bool.  But for (int j=65;j!=91;j^=32,j+=(j<91)) is shorter, you do not need those parenthesis?

Comment: @Swift I put in extra (); I believe you, but I'd have to manually check order of operations of `operator,` and I don't care enough?  :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!

```
for (int i = 'A', j = 'a'; i <= 'Z'; i++, j++)
{
    // Body
}
```